# upper bound for $\int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{t \ln \ln t}{\ln t} dt$?

Tags: integration, approximation

What is the upper bound for

$$\int \limits_{a}^{b} \frac{t \ln \ln t}{\ln t} dt $$

A good approximation is sufficient but it should be of $o(\frac{1}{\ln^2 b  \space or \space a})$ or something better.

When I tried to find closed form using WolframAlpha, it said that this integration has no known closed form.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" upper bound?

Comment: any function that from some point, will always be bigger than this integral and will depend on $a,b$ as its variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I could cook up:

Let $t=e^{e^u}$ and $a,b>1$ so that we have

$$I=\int_{\ln(\ln(a))}^{\ln(\ln(b))}ue^{2e^u}\ du$$

Notice then that

$$e^{2e^u}=1+2e^u+2e^{2u}+\frac43e^{3u}+\frac13e^{4u}+\mathcal O(e^{5u})$$

And by integration by parts, we find that

$$I=\frac12u^2+2(u-1)e^u+\left(u-\frac12\right)e^{2u}+\frac4{27}\left(3u-1\right)e^{3u}+\frac1{48}\left(4u-1\right)e^{4u}\bigg|_{\ln(\ln(a))}^{\ln(\ln(b))}\\+\mathcal O\left(\ln^5(b)\ln(\ln(b))\right)-\mathcal O\left(\ln^5(a)\ln(\ln(a))\right)$$

Comment: how about $t^2 \frac{ 1+\ln \ln t}{\ln t}|_{a}^{b}$ , is this a valid upper bound ?!, i worked backward and tried to guess the function that its derivative is slightly bigger than $t \frac{\ln \ln t}{\ln t}$ and i end up with the function above!

Comment: If anything, you should be using $\frac12t^2\frac{1+\ln(\ln(t))}{\ln(t)}$ which comes straightforwardly since $\frac{1+\ln(\ln(t))}{\ln(t)}$ is near constant, so you could try ignoring that.  I didn't check it since I don't have the computation power with me, so...

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{t^2}{2}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(\log\log t\right)^2\,dt =\left.\frac{1}{2}\left(t\log\log t\right)^2\right|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}t\left(\log\log t\right)^2\,dt$$
can be approximated very well by noticing that $\log\log t$ is approximately constant on small intervals. Without further informations on the behaviour of $a$ and $b$ this is the best I am able to give.

Comment: $a,b$ can be any two arbitrary numbers for example the gap between $a,b$ can be small or large, but they both positive real numbers and $b$ is bigger than $a$, also i am interested in the case when $a$ is very very small compared to $b$